# How can my AWS SNS service leverage a 10DLC from another account?

Tags: amazon-sns

I have two AWS accounts - let's call them "*sender*" and "*worker*". Sender has the 10 digit long code (10DLC) set up and it works for sending SMS. Worker determines when a notification should be sent and publishes to SNS.

How can SNS in the worker account leverage the 10DLC in the sender account?

The worker currently is unaware of any origination numbers (10DLC), and therefore cannot send.

The AWS documentation is very unclear on this : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-settings-sms-crossaccount-10dlc.html . It appears to only address the scenario of a logged in user account performing the send operation from the console. At that, it switches to the *sender* account in order to do it.

I'm aware of this question:
[AWS 10DLC cross account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67689530/aws-10dlc-cross-account)
, but in it a lambda function specifies the originating number. In my scenario there are many subscribers to an SNS topic, and the sending function shouldn't be aware of the 10DLC configuration.

I have tried to perform the actions described in the AWS doc link above. It does nothing to permit adding new SMS subscribers, since there is no known origination number.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the 10DLC number in the sender account by having the worker assume a role in the sender account (meaning that it temporarily becomes the sender account) and then calling SNS publish from there. Since the service sees this message as coming from the sender account, it will be able to leverage the 10DLC.

If your goal is to add subscribers to an existing topic in the sender account, the same method can be used.

So, you might have an IAM role called `SMSSender` in the sender account. This role needs to have permission to access SNS and publish, create subscriptions, etc. depending on your use case. The worker then leverages [AssumeRole](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html) to use this role (becoming the sender account) to execute the operation.